# jUnit comprobar el funcionamiento del método pedirNumero

Tags: java, poo, netbeans, class, junit

Tengo el siguiente método:

```
public static int pedirNumero() {
    int num = 0;
    boolean repetir = false;
    do {
        try {
            repetir = false;
            num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Inserta un número"));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No has insertado un número", "Numero incorrecto", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            repetir=true;
        }
    } while (repetir);
    return num;
}
```

Y quiero probarlo en jUnit.

Por ejemplo con el número 5 y también al insertar un carácter, por ejemplo 'x' para que me salte la excepción.

Se probar métodos cuando hay que pasarlos variables, por ejemplo con el método sumar(int sum1, int sum2). Pero en este método, como se pide una variable dentro del método, no se como pasarselo en el test de jUnit.

¿Me podéis ayudar?

Gracias.

ClaseTest:

```
ublic class CalculadoraTest {

Calculadora calc;

public CalculadoraTest() {
}

@BeforeAll
public static void setUpClass() {
}

@AfterAll
public static void tearDownClass() {
}

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    
    //calc = new Calculadora ();
    
    
}

@AfterEach
public void tearDown() {
}

// TODO add test methods here.
// The methods must be annotated with annotation @Test. For example:
//
// @Test
// public void hello() {}

@Test
public void testSumarPositivo () {
    
    assertEquals(15, calc.sumar (5, 10));
}

@Test
public void testSumarNegativo () {
    
    assertEquals(0, calc.sumar (-5, 5));
}

@Test
public void testMultiplicar () {
    
    assertEquals("5 x 0=0\n5 x 1=5\n5 x 2=10\n5 x 3=15\n5 x 4=20\n5 x 5=25\n"
            + "5 x 6=30\n5 x 7=35\n5 x 8=40\n5 x 9=45\n", calc.multiplicar (5));
}

@Test
public void testPedirNumero () {
    
    Calculadora calc = new Calculadora();
    int num1 = 7;
    
    //assertEquals("No vale", calc.pedirNumero());
    assertEquals(num1, calc.pedirNumero());
}
```

Por ejemplo en el último test, al lanzarlo, me sale el método pidiendo un número por teclado. Yo no quiero que haga eso, yo quiero que ese número que me pide por teclado sea el que le doy por código. Porque lo siguiente que quiero hacer es pasar un carácter y que me comprueba si el objeto que me lanza es el mismo que el que le voy a pasar yo en el assertEquals.

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Comment: Pues el comportamiento deseado sería que si al insertar un carácter me saltase la excepción y me pasase el test de junit.